# Aspect Ratios in Unity's Android builds

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen-orientation, aspect-ratio

I am building a demo app in Unity for Android. The problem I'm encountering is this big black bar of black space left on the screen, that too on one side. Here are some screenshots.

[Screenshot in Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXLHX.jpg)

[Screenshot in Potrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iZOr.jpg)

It's not the android bar, at least it doesn't appear to be. Here's a screenshot :

[Screenshot with Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK5nm.jpg)

As seen above, the bar is translucent and on the other side of the blank space.

I can't figure out why this is happening, although I suspect it has something to do with the aspect ratio of the screen. Thoughts?

The device is Redmi Note 5 Pro and I'm using Unity 2017.1.0f3

EDIT : Here are the screenshots of Game and Scene View as well as the Main Camera's inspector window.

[Game View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfLuU.png)

[Scene View Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2td2.png)

[Camera Inspector Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BRMq.jpg)

This is not an issue on builds for PC

[PC Build Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyQQz.png)

Comment: Do you see this in builds on other platforms?

Comment: Also, it would help if we could get screenshots of your scene and game views, as well as the inspector for your camera.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be an issue in other builds. I've tried a Win build and added a screenshot in the post. Also added other screenshots of Game View, Scene View and Inspector Window for the Main Camera.

Comment: Can you try a newer unity version? And on a different android phone?